# How to re-render after state is changed in react js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rendering

```
import React from 'react'

export default function App(){
    const[flag,setFlag] =React.useState({1:false,2:false})

    const change=(id)=>{
        flag[id] = !flag[id]
        setFlag(flag)
        console.log(flag)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {flag[1] ? <p>this is true</p> : <p>this is false</p>}
            <button onClick={()=>change(1)}>Change</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to change my output based on flag state. While flag JSON is changing, but it's not re-rendering.

Comment: after changing flag, am using setFlag(flag). Can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state updater returned by useState will not rerender the component's children if you set a new value that equals the current value. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

```
    function App() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = React.useState({ 1: false, 2: false });

  const change = id => {
    var newFlag = Object.assign({}, flag);
    newFlag[id] = !flag[id];
    setFlag(newFlag);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {flag[1] ? (
        <p>this is true</p>
      ) : (
        <p>this is false</p>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => change(1)}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codepen example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-benz-yd3bq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine.

```
const change=(id)=>{
   console.log(flag[id]);
        flag[id] = !flag[id]
        setFlag(flag)
        console.log(flag)
    }
```

Could you check the render method.

Check here https://codepen.io/palash924332931/pen/VwYpwOq?editors=1111

Comment: by setting setFlag({flag:flag}) , it'll create json inside a json. In functional component we shouldn't setState like this.

Comment: Could you check the render method? I have seen that it is working properly.

Comment: Code is shared in the given url.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `setFlag()` to change the state instead of changing `flag` directly. By using the setter for the `flag` state, you can call `render()` if you use `setFlag()`. In order to use `setFlag()` with your current setup, you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) like so:

```
const change = id => {
  setFlag(currentFlag => ({[id]: !currentFlag}));
}
```